# Read only user's names from txt file [C++]

Tags: c++, file-io, fstream, ifstream

```
ifstream file;
file.open("Data.txt");

string name;

while (file >> name) {
    cout << name << endl;
}
```

So i have a text file where the following information is stored about a user: Name, Weight, Height and previous heights. How would i only output the user's names and nothing else.

[image]

Comment: How can a person shrink?  Owen's maximum height is 96, then shrinks to 92, then grows to 94.  Also, what is the floating point number represent?

Comment: Owen is secretly Stretch Armstrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read one line with `std::getline` and store the name read. Then discard the next four lines with `file.ignore(std::numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n')` to reach the next line with a name.

Repeat until `getline` or `ignore` fail.

[Documentation for `std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)

[Documentation for `std::istream::ignore`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore)

[Documentation for `std::numeric_limits::max`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max)